# Generating (&saving) Energy from Charged Particles

Tags: electrostatics, energy, atmospheric-science

This is highly theoretical and i need expert advice on this.
There are charged particles in the atmosphere
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307435997_Charged_Particles_in_Atmosphere

Now imagine if a object could harvest those energy through direct flight inside the upper atmosphere and load a battery or some kind of storage, similar to hygroelectricity.
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-52374-3_6
I figured these methods:

```
1. Fermi acceleration
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_acceleration
would use a magnetic mirror
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_mirror

2. Electrostatic motors
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_motor
```

This is about if its possible, the idea how to bring such generators up there is allready in my mind but has no matter if theres no way to solve the "harvesting"

Comment: It's not about whether it's possible simply to harvest energy, but to harvest more energy than it takes to do the harvesting.  Very unlikely in this case. And it's not clear how you would use those charges to power anything

Comment: as far i noticed its only a problem if it needs to be converted, but its allready ionized up there so the harvesting would not need the energy consuming part except going up there before

Comment: That's what I mean. Whatever flying plane device you are using, or even a ground based fan to pull air in, will need to run on less power than you would be able to generate by harvesting, in order for this to be used as an energy source.

Comment: Also, it would be extremely difficult to store these charges, since literally anything they touched (air, walls of a chamber) would neutralize them.  It would be like trying to balance a pencil on its tip indefinitely

Comment: could you explain that further? its contrary to what ive heard from a physics help forum

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish with this idea?